# XML Parse into Sql table - repeating values in every column

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an xml file that I am trying to parse.  However, when I parse into SQL the same value is repeated in all 7 columns and then parse looks for the next value and enters that into the next row.  The code is

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc As INT, @SQL nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLOpenGG

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML
SELECT GeneratedDateTime, RecordLocator, OutBound, Return, FirstName, LastName, TrackingNo, Location FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/CIS_PNRS/CIS_PNR/PNRDataItems/PNRDataItem')
WITH (
GeneratedDateTime varchar(50) '.',
RecordLocator varchar(50) '.',
Outbound varchar(50) '.',
Return varchar(50) '.',
FirstName varchar(100) '.',
LastName varchar(100) '.',
TrackingNo varchar(50) '.',
Location varchar(100) '.')
```

The XML File structure looks like this (I have removed all values as they are sensitive);

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CIS_PNRS>
 <CIS_PNR>
  <PNRDataItems>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
   <PNRDataItem Name=""></PRNDataItem>
  </PNRDataItems>
 </CIS_PNR>
</CIS_PNRS>
```

Any help would be so great!

Comment: Whats your expected result format

Comment: I want to add certain PNRDataItem values to the corresponding columns in SQL.